# Can someone explain the difference between a deep copy and a defensive copy?

Tags: java

My professor said they are completely different, but I read they are pretty similar. I don't know what context 'different' he was referring to.
And if this question as already been answered just link it. Thanks.

Comment: Just the purpose.  A deep copy means you copy every element (without specifying the reason), and a defensive copy means you copy to prevent anyone else from accessing the same object (e.g. for thread safety).

Comment: I can drive to work in a Toyota but driving to work is completely different from a Toyota. One is a type of car, one is a way that a car is used. A deep copy is a type of copy and a defensive copy is a way that a copy is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Deep copy**: a kind of object copying techniques: copying all data in the structure deeply. A "harsh" method to produce a deep copy of an object is to serialize then deserialize it. For trees, generally, recursive copying is an efficient solution.

**Defensive copy:** result of an operation to protect internal data. Usually it is a deep or shallow copy used to prevent undesirable access through an internal reference result. For example:

```java
public int[] getValues() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
}
```

In general, you should use defensive copy to protect an inner array, collection or other structure. If we simply returned with (a reference to) the array, user could modify our internal structure!

Let's see an example.

Tom writes a class which lazily caches some aggregations of an `Integer` collection:

```java
public class CachedIntegerAggregator {

    private List<Integer> integers;

    private boolean isSumCalculated = false;
    private int sum = 0;

    private boolean isMultiCalculated = false;
    private int multi = 0;

    public CachedIntegerAggregator(Integer... integers) {
        this(Arrays.asList(integers));
    }

    public CachedIntegerAggregator(Collection<Integer> integers) {
        this.integers = new ArrayList<Integer>(integers);
    }

    public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
        return integers;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        if (!isSumCalculated) {
            sum = 0;
            for (Integer integer: integers) {
                sum += integer;
            }
            isSumCalculated = true;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int getMulti() {
        if (!isMultiCalculated) {
            multi = 1;
            for (Integer integer: integers) {
                multi *= integer;
            }
            isMultiCalculated = true;
        }
        return multi;
    }

}
```

Jerry uses the above class in this way:

```java
CachedIntegerAggregator aggregator = new CachedIntegerAggregator(2, 3, 4);

// hm, what is the sum?
System.out.println(aggregator.getSum());

// let's print of integers
List<Integer> integers = aggregator.getIntegers();
System.out.println(integers);

// now, see the double
int size = integers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // (oops! this changes internal data!)
    integers.set(i, integers.get(i) * 2);
}
System.out.println(integers);

// hm, see sum and multi
System.out.println(aggregator.getSum());
System.out.println(aggregator.getMulti()); // (oops! total inconsistency!)
```

Output:

```
9
[2, 3, 4]
[4, 6, 8]
9
192
```

What is the main problem? Tom leaks a mutable internal structure. What is the solution? In `getIntegers()` make a copy of it before return:

```java
public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(integers);
}
```

In some cases, an immutable wrapper whould be also right:

```java
public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(integers);
}
```

Performance? Generally, do not worry about it. Fast object creation is one of the major Java advantages. Of course, there are complex structures, which will be copied inefficiently. In this case, you can use copy-on-write technique. Some big data structure implementations have built in copy-on-write support, such as [BigList](http://www.magicwerk.org/page-collections-overview.html).

Comment: Defensive copies don't have to be deep copies. Say I have a `class Foo { private Widget[] widgets; ...}` where `Widget` is mutable and I have a method that returns my `widgets`. I can shallow copy the array to keep the outside world from modifying the internal details of my `Foo` but I don't have to copy every `Widget` for it to be a defensive copy.

Comment: Correct. I changed the text.

Comment: @Radiodef I don't understand how can a defensive copy be a shallow copy? If you use shallow copy then the receiver can modify the internal of the object which is not a defensive copy.

Comment: @Nier In my example I want to keep people from modifying my array so I copy it. I don't care if they modify the actual widgets, so I only defensively copy the array. In fact, maybe it's not an array of `Widget` at all, but some generic type and I have no idea what it actually is. When I copy the array, it's a defensive copy.

Comment: @Radiodef As far as I know, defensive copy is used when you want to return a mutable object field to the caller. In your case if you return the array, receiver can modify or even replace the object that the array stored. For example, receiver can use `widgets[0] = null` to replace the first element of your array. I don't think it's a defensive copy.

Comment: @Nier If I copy the array they can't do that and it's a defensive copy. I think you are misunderstanding my comment somehow. A shallow copy is when you have a mutable object (such as an array) which contains mutable objects and you only copy the container (array).

Comment: @Nier Please have a look at this code example which hopefully clarifies: http://ideone.com/8fB7d4.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for the clarifies, in this case I think it's create a new array and copy all references to the new one. It's a little bit tricky because it's a mixed of shallow and deep copy. Anyway, I agree that the comment you leave at OP about "defensive copy is a way that a copy is used", and not bound to deep copy.

Comment: @Radiodef Thank you so much for the clarification. Makes a lot more sense now.